# groupby and orderby rand() using mysql

Tags: mysql

```
table structure

questions_id    category_id
     1              1
     2              1
     3              2
     4              2
     5              3
     6              3
```

my query

```
SELECT * FROM questions GROUP BY category_id ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0, 3
```

it's display  any three question_id's

```
SET @row_number = 0;
select (@row_number := @row_number+1) AS num, id, question_name, 
category_id FROM questions ORDER BY RAND()  LIMIT 8;
```

display any 8 questions_id's

another one

```
SELECT * FROM questions a 
INNER JOIN (SELECT category_id FROM questions GROUP BY category_id) AS b
ON a.category_id = b.category_id
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0, 3
```

it's also display same, but i want each category_id are equal question_id
......

Comment: `another one` ?? where? how?  are you displaying  questions on a html page, then expecting a user click, and that click selects "another question" which you want to be from the same category? **Please add more explanation of what you are asking for.**

Comment: yes displaying html page and all category_id's and questions_id's only one page total display 3 questions each category one question  I am trying two query's but two query's display any three questions on page

Comment: Your question is close to gibberish, please post a sample output of what you want.

Comment: if using PHP add that the tags, if C# add that to the tags etc. This is NOT a MySQL issue, you need to control what you request from MySQL from your frontend

Comment: <tr>
<?php $main_qustions_query=$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM questions a INNER JOIN (SELECT category_id FROM questions GROUP BY category_id) AS b ON a.category_id = b.category_id ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0, 3") or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
$i=1; while($main_questions_row = $main_questions_query->fetch_array()) { ?>
 <td class="text-center"><?php echo $i; ?></td>
 <td class="text-center"><?php echo    $main_question_row['question_id']; ?></td>
 </tr>
 <?php ++$i; } ?>

Comment: I have tried many things but have not figured it out how to get same number of rows for each group.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, question_name, category_id FROM
(
    SELECT id, question_name, category_id, @rn := IF(@prev = category_id, 
    @rn + 1, 1) AS rn, @prev := category_id
    FROM questions JOIN (SELECT @prev := NULL, @rn := 0) AS vars ORDER BY  
    category_id
) AS T1
WHERE rn <= 2 ORDER BY RAND()
```